# JQuery positioning: I can scroll to the right place once but not twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I recently started trying to mimic scrolling to a particular anchor in jQuery (tl;dr jumping to the anchor broke the outside of the page).

While the suggestions I've found on StackOverflow work for the first attempt to scroll down the page, I have found the second attempt isn't so successful.

I've probably been thinking about this too long, but I do have a Fiddle based on my woes:

http://jsfiddle.net/txns8bep/

```
var doThis = function() {
    var parent = $('#crud');
    var parentTop = $('#crud').offset().top;
    var targetTop = $('#2').offset().top;

    $(parent).animate({
        scrollTop: targetTop// - parentTop
    });
    console.log('doThis() called. Went to '+targetTop+'-'+parentTop);
};

// works the first time
doThis();

// doesn't work the second time
setTimeout(doThis, 1000);
```

And the HTML (in part) is as follows:

```
<div id="crud" style="position:absolute;top:100px;bottom:0;overflow:scroll; border:1px solid red;">
    <h1 id="1">Item #1</h1>Lorem ipsum....
    <h1 id="2">Item #2</h1>Ab magnam...
    <h1 id="3">Item #3</h1>Mollitia eius...
    <!-- (h1[id=$]{Item #$}+lipsum)*10 -->
```

This problem isn't just about post-scrolling, though. ANY attempt to scroll to the relevant area is thwarted if the present offset top is greater than 0.

(Maybe it's just the caffeine talking, here, but I'm stumped.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was staring me in the face: `scrollTop()`. I modified the animation function as follows, and everything worked:

```
var newScrollTop = parent.scrollTop() + target.offset().top - parent.offset().top;
$(parent).animate({
    scrollTop: newScrollTop
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/txns8bep/1/